# How to refresh the markers without refreshing the Google Map in Vaadin?

Tags: java, google-maps, vaadin7

I am using GoogleMap add on, by tapio,  with Vaadin 7. Everything seems to be working fine, except for the refresh. I tried a bean container as follows:

```
BeanContainer<String, GoogleMap> maps;
maps = new BeanContainer<String, GoogleMap>(GoogleMap.class);
```

When I want to add or delete a marker, I recreate the GoogleMap and update the Bean Container maps. I tried requestRepaintAll, although it is deprecated. I would appreciate if you can guide me on how to refresh the markers without refreshing the whole page/map.

a) is it possible to just refresh the markers without affecting the map?

b) if Vaadin is using Ajax to send updates to the client, how can I make it work for the markers?

c) is it possible to refresh the map with markers without using javascript location.reload()

Thank you

Comment: I now find that GoogleMap.addMarker method when run on a separate thread or in the main thread is not adding the marker in real-time. If I use Thread.sleep(1000), after creating a new marker and before calling addMarker, the marker is properly displayed. Wondering why the Thread.sleep required and if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with CustomComponent as follows:

```
BeanContainer<String, VaadinGoogleMap> map;
...
googleMap = new GoogleMap(new LatLon(39.5, -98.35), 4.0, googleApiKey);
map.addBean(new VaadinGoogleMap("mymap", googleMap);
mapComposite = new MapComposite(map);
...

class MyComposite extends CustomComponent {
    public MyComposite(BeanContainer<String, VaadinGoogleMap> bc) {
        // A layout structure used for composition
        Panel panel = new Panel("My Custom Component");

        // Compose from multiple components
        panel.setContent(bc.getItem("mymap").getBean().getGoogleMap());

        // The composition root MUST be set
        setCompositionRoot(panel);
    }
}
```